# How to dynamically map functions to serverless.yml

Tags: serverless-framework

My team has been working with serverless and we're trying to establish a new standard in the company for a file organization that eases the collaborative development.

We plan to isolate the lambdas/functions handler each in their folder, alongside the function .yml file and other necessary configs.

Example expected directory structure (lean):

```
-- /app
--- /functions
---- /func_a
-----  func_a.py
-----  func_a.yml
---- /func_b
-----  func_b.py
-----  func_b.yml
- serverles.yml
```

The problem so far is that we have to manually declare all external config function files in the serverless.yml file, which breaks the whole purpose of the idea.

The question is: is there a way to automate this import?

What we've searched so far:

1. Wildcard path - does not work for file variables. Eg.: ${file(./app/functions/*.yml)} or ${file(./app/functions/{any+})}
2. Extending configuration using custom plugins - does not seem to be able to modify the functions list. Only found information about: DefineTopLevelProperty, defineCustomProperties, defineFunctionEvent, defineFunctionEventProperties, defineFunctionProperties, defineProvider.

Info from here: [Serverless Doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/plugins/custom-configuration#top-level-properties-via-definetoplevelproperty) - base schema link broken, so no other information aside from the one in the page.

What we thought to be options:

1. Maybe is there a plugin that does that? Didn't find any.
2. Create an isolated custom function (python) that is called before running `sls deploy` and creates the final serverles.yml file from a template by traversing all folders.

What is the better and most natural approach to that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that for your use case, you might be better of with considering using JS/TS configuration file format instead of YAML. That allows you to use regular JS to define your config which makes importing such parts of configurations much easier. See the TS template for example on how to use it: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript/serverless.ts

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We'll try it!